# String manipulation within a column (pandas): split, replace, join

Tags: python, pandas, string

I'd like to create a new column based on the following conditions:

- if the row contains dogs/dog/chien/chiens, then add -00
- if the row contains cats/cat/chat/chats, then add 00-

A sample of data is as follows:

```
Animal 

22 dogs
1 dog
1 cat
3 dogs
32 chats
```

and so far.

I'd like as output a column with only numbers (numerical):

```
Animal        New column

22 dogs       22-00
1 dog         1-00
1 cat         00-1
3 dogs        3-00
32 chats      00-32
```

I think I should use an `if` condition to check the words, then `.split` and `.join` . It's about string manipulation but I'm having trouble breaking down this problem.

Comment: Is your sample data always in the form `^\d+ \w+$` or can `dogs`, `cats` etc be in arbitrary contexts? In other words, is `"there were 22 cats in dogville"` a possible cell value, and if so, what should be done with it?

Comment: No, it should be in the format numeric + string/character

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
PRES = set(("cats", "cat", "chat", "chats"))
POSTS = set(("dogs", "dog", "chien", "chiens"))

def fun(words):
    # words will come as e.g. "22 dogs"
    num, ani = words.split()
    if ani in PRES:
        return "00-" + num
    elif ani in POSTS:
        return num + "-00"
    else:
        # you might want to handle this..
        return "unexpected"

df["New Column"] = df["Animal"].apply(fun)
```

where `df` is your dataframe. For a fast lookup, we turn the condition lists into sets. Then we *apply* a function to values of the `Animal` column of `df` and act accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this, first extract the number, then use `np.where` to conditionally add characters to the string:

```
df['New Col'] = df['Animal'].str.extract(r'([0-9]*)')
df['New Col'] = np.where(df['Animal'].str.contains('dogs|dog|chiens|chien'), df['New Col']+'-00', df['New Col'])
df['New Col'] = np.where(df['Animal'].str.contains('cats|cat|chat|chats'), '00-'+df['New Col'], df['New Col'])
print(df)

     Animal New Col
0   22 dogs   22-00
1     1 dog    1-00
2     1 cat    00-1
3    3 dogs    3-00
4  32 chats   00-32
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your data is well-formatted, you can use a basic substitution and `apply` it to the row:

```
import pandas as pd
import re

def replacer(s):
    return re.sub(r" (chiens?|dogs?)", "-00", 
                  re.sub(r"(\d+) ch?ats?", r"00-\1", s))

df = pd.DataFrame({"Animal": ["22 dogs", "1 dog", "1 cat", "3 dogs", "32 chats"]})
df["New Column"] = df["Animal"].apply(replacer)
```

Output:

```
     Animal New Column
0   22 dogs      22-00
1     1 dog       1-00
2     1 cat       00-1
3    3 dogs       3-00
4  32 chats      00-32
```

Answer (score 0):

Using re:

```
import re

list1 = ['dogs', 'dog', 'chien', 'chiens']
list2 = ['cats', 'cat', 'chat', 'chats']

df['New_col'] = [(re.search(r'(\w+)', val).group(1).strip()+"-00") if re.search(r'([a-zA-Z]+)', val).group(1).strip() in list1 else ("00-" + re.search(r'(\w+)', val).group(1).strip()) if re.search(r'([a-zA-Z]+)', val).group(1).strip() in list2 else val for val in list(df['Animal'])]

print(df)
```

Output:

```
     Animal New_col
0   22 dogs   22-00
1     1 dog    1-00
2     1 cat    00-1
3    3 dogs    3-00
4  32 chats   00-32
```

Answer (score 0):

Create tuple of search words

```
dog = ('dogs', 'dog', 'chien', 'chiens')
cat = ('cats', 'cat', 'chat', 'chats')
```

Create conditions for each tuple created with corresponding replacements and apply the conditions to the column, using **[numpy select](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html)** :

```
num = df.Animal.str.split().str[0] #the numbers
#conditions
cond1 = df.Animal.str.endswith(dog)        
cond2 = df.Animal.str.endswith(cat)
condlist = [cond1,cond2]
#what should be returned for each successful condition
choicelist = [num+"-00","00-"+num]

df['New Column'] = np.select(condlist,choicelist)
df

    Animal    New Column
0   22 dogs     22-00
1   1 dog       1-00
2   1 cat       00-1
3   3 dogs      3-00
4   32 chats    00-32
```